# Difficulty in python reading and writing to arduinos connected to serial ports

Tags: python, arduino

I'm working with a python program on a Windows PC running under Anaconda that is talking to multiple USB-attached arduino megas. I can create a string on the python side and successfully encode it as bytes and send it to the arduino where it is correctly interpreted. I can read a string from the arduino into the python program and correctly interpret it. The issue I'm having is when I try to read from one arduino and then send that message back out to another arduino. Example:

Python side code:

```
  response = ser1.readline()  #Read from arduino #1

  ser2.write(response)        #Write the response read from #1 out to #2
```

Arduino side (for serial 2):

```
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    newStr = Serial.readString();
  }
```

The Serial.readString() never completes; the arduino just hangs at that point.

I'm sure it's something stupidly simple, but python is a new language for me so I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: first you should see what you get in Python and compare it with data which you send from `arduino`. Maybe it needs extra char at the end to inform that it is end of data. You should also check if you really connected to second `arduino`. Do you have this problem when you connect directly two arduinos?

Comment: some systems use buffer for sended data and they send only when there is special char. ie. `sys.stdout.()` sends text on screen only when there is `\n' at the end. `file.write()` can send data on disk only when you run `file.close()`. In both situations you may use `flush` to force system to send data. So you may check if `ser2.flush()` can help.